# module was expected to contain an assembly manifest Visual Studio 2010 error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I encountered a Visual Studio error while using Visual Basic. All my programs refuse to compile and run. here is the error stated

> Error while trying to run project. Could not load life or assembly
>   'myprogram' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to
>   contain an assembly manifest

I tried switching the framework etc. but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post the build log ?

Comment: What actions did you do before this happened?

Comment: can you paste your .vbproj file? there's something related to build actions in there.

Comment: You need to check the external references you have added in your project (try adding them again). Also, if you have more than one projects and referred amongst them check them one by one. It is possible that some of your project's reference gets removed from the other one.

Comment: I run the program and existed but when I started it today, it was showing this error. Where can I find the build log. You mean I should post all the .vbproj file text?

Comment: Are you trying to publish your application using ClickOnce? My advice: don't.

Comment: No, am not publishing just yet. I just wanted to execute the program but its failing to run even after build is successful.

Comment: Did you install or uninstall any software on your computer, you may have removed something your program is looking for.

Comment: You'll need to use Fuslogvw.exe, start it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Post the trace it produces for the failed bind in your question if you need more help.

Comment: I have uninstall so many things but if that's the case won't reinstalling it install the files back. I copied the project folder to my friends computer and it executed without a hitch. Guess its some Visual Studio bug.

Comment: Please, How can I use the Fuslogvw.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
Turn off your firewall and/or antivirus and create a new project with NOTHING added to it.

Try to run the project, clean. 
If you still have that error, it means that your VB.NET is corrupted or broken. You will have to reinstall.
If you do not get the error when your firewall/antivirus is off, then it's your firewall/antivirus causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help but it did not work. I guess its corrupted although I have uninstall and reinstall more than 10 times